# Python: How to shutdown a threaded HTTP server with persistent connections (how to kill readline() from another thread)?

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets

I'm using python2.6 with `HTTPServer` and the `ThreadingMixIn`, which will handle each request in a separate thread.  I'm also using HTTP1.1 persistent connections ('Connection: keep-alive'), so neither the server or client will close a connection after a request.

Here's roughly what the request handler looks like

```
request, client_address = sock.accept()
rfile = request.makefile('rb', rbufsize)
wfile = request.makefile('wb', wbufsize)

global server_stopping
while not server_stopping:
    request_line = rfile.readline() # 'GET / HTTP/1.1'
    # etc - parse the full request, write to wfile with server response, etc
wfile.close()
rfile.close()
request.close()
```

The problem is that if I stop the server, there will still be a few threads waiting on `rfile.readline()`.

I would put a `select([rfile, closefile], [], [])` above the `readline()` and write to closefile when I want to shutdown the server, but I don't think it would work on windows because `select` only works with sockets.

My other idea is to keep track of all the running requests and `rfile.close()` but I get Broken pipe errors.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there—the correct approach is to call `rfile.close()` and to catch the broken pipe errors and exit your loop when that happens.

Answer (score 1):

If you set `daemon_threads` to true in your `HTTPServer` subclass, the activity of the threads will not prevent the server from exiting.

```
class ThreadedHTTPServer(ThreadingMixIn, HTTPServer):
    daemon_threads = True
```

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't seem like good practice to leave the threads open.

Answer (score 0):

You could work around the Windows problem by making `closefile` a socket, too -- after all, since it's presumably something that's opened by your main thread, it's up to you to decide whether to open it as a socket or a file;-).

Comment: Does request.makefile return a socket?

Comment: `makefile` returns a file-like object whose `fileno` is a socket. Whether that lets you select on it in Windows, I don't know (I don't do Windows, and haven't in 10 years or so, even though it's as a Windows guru that I used to make my living back then;-), but I suspect it does.